# How to customize apps preference screen (two-pane layout) for tabs below 10"

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

I've the following problem. I'm using the following code ([Settings @ android.developer.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#PreferenceHeaders)) to generate the perefence activity and fragments to get the single or two-pane layout depending on the device. But sadly the two-pane layout (see link above figure 4) is only shown on 10" devices. The same seems to happen when using the gmail app. Therefore I guess it's the default setting. On 8.4" devices and below the single-pane layout is shown (see link above figure 5). Is it possible with reasonable effort to enable the two-pane layout for 7" devices and bigger (SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found. It can be customized by overriding the following function (see [PreferenceActivity , PreferenceFragment and headers (Part 2)](http://gmariotti.blogspot.de/2013/01/preferenceactivity-preferencefragment_28.html)):

```
/**
 * Called to determine if the activity should run in multi-pane mode.
 * The default implementation returns true if the screen is large
 * enough.
 */
public boolean onIsMultiPane() {
    boolean preferMultiPane = getResources().getBoolean(
            com.android.internal.R.bool.preferences_prefer_dual_pane);
    return preferMultiPane;
}
```